# Why is there an initial delay for the progress bar filling up? (Vb.Net)

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a game in VB.NET. It involves launching projectiles at spawned enemies. I have an energy bar that is supposed to fill up while you hold space bar, and then launch the projectile when you let go. However, there seems to be a 1-2s delay between when you press the key, and when the progress bar starts progressing. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Game
    Dim rad As Double = 60 * (Math.PI / 180)
    Dim v As Double = 0
    Dim vx As Integer = 0
    Dim vy As Integer = 0
    Const g As Double = -4.9
    Dim deg As Char = Chr(176)
    Dim Goblins As List(Of PictureBox) = New List(Of PictureBox)
    Dim launching As Boolean = False

    Private Sub frmProjectilePT_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tmeCreateGoblin.Enabled = True
        tmeMoveGoblin.Enabled = True
        tmeDetect.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmProjectilePT_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
            v += 1
            tmeIncSpeed.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmProjectilePT_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space And Not v = 0 Then
            tmeIncSpeed.Enabled = False
            box.Top = 300
            box.Left = 0
            vx = (v * Math.Abs(Math.Cos(rad))) / 2
            vy = v * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(rad))
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("G:\Course\Buhot Computer Sci 1 P1 J441-1\Drop Off\Project\App Project 2\Ben And Liams Experiments Continued\11B-X-1371\11B-X-1371\Projects\New folder\New folder\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\My Project\ni.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
            tmeProjMove.Enabled = True
            launching = True
            v = 0
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmeProjMove_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles tmeProjMove.Tick
        If box.Top > Me.Height Then
            tmeProjMove.Enabled = False
            launching = False
            v = 0
        Else
            box.Left += vx
            box.Top -= vy
            vy += g
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmeCreateGoblin_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmeCreateGoblin.Tick
        CreateGoblin()
        Dim r As Integer = Int((7001 - 1000) * Rnd()) + 1000
        tmeCreateGoblin.Interval = r
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmeMoveGoblin_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmeMoveGoblin.Tick
        For Each goblin As PictureBox In Goblins
            goblin.Left -= 50
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub CreateGoblin()
        Dim goblin As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
        With goblin
            .Size = New Size(50, 50)
            .Location = New Point(Me.Width, Me.Height - .Height)
            .BackColor = Color.Red
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(goblin)
        Goblins.Add(goblin)
    End Sub

    Sub RemoveGoblin(ByRef goblin As PictureBox)
        Me.Controls.Remove(goblin)
        Goblins.Remove(goblin)
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmeDetect_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmeDetect.Tick
        meter.Value = If(v <= 100, v, 100)
        For Each goblin As PictureBox In Goblins
            If goblin.Left <= 0 Then
                RemoveGoblin(goblin)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If launching Then
            For Each goblin As PictureBox In Goblins
                If box.Top < (goblin.Top + goblin.Height) And box.Left < (goblin.Left + goblin.Width) And (box.Top + box.Height) > goblin.Top And (box.Left + box.Width) > goblin.Left Then
                    RemoveGoblin(goblin)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        For Each goblin As PictureBox In Goblins
            If goblin.Top < (knightsofni.Top + knightsofni.Height) And goblin.Left < (knightsofni.Left + knightsofni.Width) And (goblin.Top + goblin.Height) > knightsofni.Top And (goblin.Left + goblin.Width) > knightsofni.Left Then
                RemoveGoblin(goblin)
                health.Value -= 1
                If health.Value = 0 Then
                    tmeMoveGoblin.Enabled = False
                    tmeCreateGoblin.Enabled = False
                    tmeDetect.Enabled = False
                    MsgBox("Game over")
                    TitleScreen.Show()
                    Me.Close()
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmeIncSpeed_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmeIncSpeed.Tick
        v += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Its because if the animation.  You can easily use a label instead and use Red/Green/Yellow for the state, and the Text if you want for the actual amount.  As well you can use pother colors to indicate types of protection (armour, sheilds, barriers etc).

Comment: Sorry for the duplication then.